# Toggle TextView enable/disable option via ContextMenu

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of TextViews that are disabled for editing by default and are part of a list view that has a ContextMenu. I'm trying to add a button to the ContextView that enables the TextView for editing when tapped.

Row view:

```
struct PassionRowView: View {
  @Binding var passion: Passion
  
  var body: some View {
    TextField("", text: $passion.title)
      .disabled(true)
  }
}
```

List view:

```
struct PassionListView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var model: PassionsModel
    
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach($model.passions, content: PassionRowView.init)
        .onDelete(perform: model.delete)
        .contextMenu {
butt
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("My Passions")
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button(action: model.add) {
          Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
        }
      }
    }
    .animation(.default, value: model.passions)
    .listStyle(.sidebar)
  }
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach, where you have a property in your `Passion` struct that controls the text editing.

Example code:

```
struct Passion: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String = "title-1"
    var isDisabled = true  // <-- here
    // ....
}

struct PassionRowView: View {
    @Binding var passion: Passion
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $passion.title)
            .disabled(passion.isDisabled)  // <-- here
            .contextMenu {
                Button {
                    passion.isDisabled.toggle()  // <-- here
                } label: {
                    Label(passion.isDisabled ? "Disable OFF" : "Disable ON", systemImage: passion.isDisabled ? "checkmark.circle" : "x.circle")
                }
            }
    }
}

struct PassionListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: PassionsModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List ($model.passions) { $passion in   // <-- here
            PassionRowView(passion: $passion)  // <-- here
              .onDelete(perform: model.delete)
        }
        // .....
```

EDIT-1:

You could of course have just this, without modifying the `Passion` struct. It depends on what you want to do.

```
struct PassionRowView: View {
    @Binding var passion: Passion
    @State private var isDisabled = true  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $passion.title)
            .disabled(isDisabled)  // <-- here
            .contextMenu {
                Button {
                    isDisabled.toggle()  // <-- here
                } label: {
                    Label(isDisabled ? "Disable OFF" : "Disable ON", 
                          systemImage: isDisabled ? "checkmark.circle" : "x.circle")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much! Only thing I had to tweak for some reason was to make the @State var isDisabled to private. Without that I was getting some errors on initialization of the row view from the list view.

Comment: yes, you are correct, `isDisabled` should be private. I'll update my answer because it is best practice in any case.